# merging of 2 dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays

Is there any inbuilt function in C  to merge different ("n") 2 dimensional arrays into one 2 dimensional array ? If so pls let me know ...

Comment: How do you want them to be merged?? What is "n"? Is it the number of arrays to merge that you want your program to eventually scale up to? A little more clarity on "merge" is needed.

Comment: True Sriram "n" will number of 2 dimensional arrays. Merge in the sense I need them into one multidimenssional array.

Comment: Give us an example (using two 2d arrays) being merged. That might make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to write that function yourself.

Comment: This is not an answer. It is more like a comment. Please flag the question if you think it is inappropriate. Even some pseudo-code would have done, but not this.

Comment: @Sriram: The question is clear, it asks whether there is any library function to merge the multi dimensional arrays, to which I replied that there is no such function. If the OP requires help in merging that should be mentioned in the question.